# Integrity Constraint violated error when trying to insert into tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need a new set of eyes to help me understand what I'm doing wrong here!

I created these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE bankkund(
PNR VARCHAR2(11) PRIMARY KEY,
FNAMN  VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
ENAMN VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,    
PASSWD VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(PASSWD));

CREATE TABLE konto(
KNR NUMBER(8)PRIMARY KEY,
 KTNR NUMBER(6)NOT NULL,
 REGDATUM DATE NOT NULL,
 SALDO NUMBER(10,2),
 FOREIGN KEY(ktnr) REFERENCES kontotyp(ktnr));
 
 CREATE TABLE kontoägare(
 RADNR NUMBER(9)PRIMARY KEY,
 PNR VARCHAR2(11)NOT NULL,
 KNR NUMBER(8)NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY(pnr) REFERENCES bankkund(pnr),
 FOREIGN KEY(knr) REFERENCES konto(knr));
```

then this sequence:

```
create sequence radnr_seq
start with 1
increment by 1;
```

and then whenever I want to insert the following values I get an integrity constraint error:

```
INSERT INTO kontoägare(radnr,pnr,knr)
VALUES(radnr_seq.NEXTVAL,'540126-1111',123);
INSERT INTO kontoägare(radnr,pnr,knr)
VALUES(radnr_seq.NEXTVAL,'691124-4478',123);
INSERT INTO kontoägare(radnr,pnr,knr)
VALUES(radnr_seq.NEXTVAL,'540126-1111',5899);
INSERT INTO kontoägare(radnr,pnr,knr)
VALUES(radnr_seq.NEXTVAL,'691124-4478',8896);
COMMIT;
```

What am I missing??

Comment: It depends which constraint is being violated, which you haven't told us.  It could be there is no bankkund record with pnr='540126-1111' (for example), or that there is no konto record with knr = 123 (for example).

Comment: In the first insert `INSERT INTO kontoägare(radnr,pnr,knr) VALUES(radnr_seq.NEXTVAL, '540126-1111',123);` does the value `'540126-1111'` exist in `bankkund`? Does the value `123` exist in `konto`. If either doesn't exist in the related tables, the insert won't work. Foreign key constraints are doing their job to keep data consistent.

Comment: The tables are empty that's why! Thanks guys that solved the problem! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is expected. Table "kontoägare" has 2 foreign keys:  `FOREIGN KEY(pnr) REFERENCES bankkund(pnr)`and  `FOREIGN KEY(knr) REFERENCES konto(knr))`. This means that the values for "pnr"  need to exist in table "bankkund" and the value for "knr" needs to exist in "konto". If either of those values do not exist when you do the insert, an integrity constraint error will be raised.

Comment: Ohhh yeah the other tables are empty, haven't insert any values yet!! Thanks so much guys! That solved it!

Comment: Since the above answer resolved your issue kindly accept it. This helps future users having the same or similar issue, and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.